# Problemas carregar static files no Django em deploy no heroku

Tags: python-3.x, django, static

Estou tentando fazer deploy de uma app que iniciei em django no heroku, mas estou com problema para carregar os arquivos de css/js/imgs, segue abaixo como está as minhas pastas e as configurações referente ao mesmo!

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files.
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
)
```

[image: Pasta do Projeto]

Carrego o css assim:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'template/style.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css' %}" />
```

**meu problema é que consigo fazer o deploy mas não consigo carregar os static files na pagina!**

Comment: ja rodou o comando heroku run python manage.py collectstatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Talvez** o que esteja faltando é você setar para que em modo de desenvolvimento o Django sirva os arquivos estáticos. Na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) você entra o código abaixo como um *hack* no `urls.py` do seu projeto para poder fazer isso:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Tem uma maneira de já setar para que o Heroku usando o `WhiteNoise`. Vou deixar alguns links abaixo como referência pra isso.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
- http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html